# Github Pages throwing 404 'Not Found' Error but Site works when testing index.html file in browser

Tags: javascript, github-pages

https://github.com/ndsambare/resumePage.git - Here is the repository that I want to deploy using Github Pages, and here is the website url that is currently throwing the error.

https://ndsambare.github.io/resumePage/

If you could take a look and let me know why this is happening that would be great.

Comment: there is no error, even the website is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It works if you access it like this: https://ndsambare.github.io/resumePage/Bootstrap4Resume-master/

Your entire project is placed inside of `Bootstrap4Resume-master` folder which is pointless. Just place it in the root folder.

Answer (score 0):

The link to your website url is https://ndsambare.github.io/resumePage/Bootstrap4Resume-master/

The reason you are getting a 404 error is because there is no index.html file present in your root folder. Your root folder has just the folder "Bootstrap4Resume-master" and a .DS_Store file. [image: Your root Folder]

A simple way to fix this is:

- You can move out all the content in "Bootstrap4Resume-master" into the root folder.